# Magento Syntax error or access violation 1286 Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'

Tags: php, mysql, magento, syntax-error

just got a problem with my Magento Online Store.
Server: Managed Server Strato

Error LOG here:

```
    a:4:{i:0;s:85:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'";i:1;s:2165:"#0 htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(730): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store/Collection.php(174): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#10 htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Collection->load()
#11 htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(624): Varien_Data_Collection->count()
#12 htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#13 htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#14 htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 htdocs/magento/index.php(107): Mage::run()
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:17:"/en/buy-sell.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I dont know where is the Problem and the Solution for this Problem.
Frontend WHITE / Backend Error...

Comment: your mysql doesn't have innodb enabled.

Comment: YES. Just tried in PHPmyAdmin to click any DB Entry and get error: #1286 - Unknown table engine 'InnoDB' ... :( suddenly

Answer (score 4):

**** Check before you try this ****

First of all, you need to replace the log file

issue, stop mysql completely:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

then move the files

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0.bak
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1.bak
```

after that issue to start mysql back up

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

InnoDB is enabled by default, MySQL disables it automatically if your InnoDB log files get corrupted. When you remove them, they are recreated, allowing InnoDB to start again.

Give it a shot.

Comment: check your my.cnf file to make sure innoDB isn't disabled there.

Answer (score 1):

**First understand the issue -** 
It simply means that table has been crashed and needs to get repaired.

**Simple Solution -**

Just get the DB restarted either yourself or through your server provider tech team. Issue will resolve in seconds

Error files can be visible at this location - /var/lib/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by unixmiah you need to replace or remove the log files in the mysql folder and then restart mysqld:

service mysqld restart

BUT, sometimes Magento even if phpmyadmin starts working again, it continues to retrieve that error. Remove cache won't help.
You need to rename the local.xml file in /app/etc/ .. open any page of magento. And after that rename localRENAMED.xml back to local.xml. 
Seems odd but it worked for me.

Comment: I did what you suggested but now I'm getting a strange error message: "dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract". Very weird...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by forcing a graceful restart in WHM. I didn't try the innoDB solution but that seemed logical.

Answer (score -2):

The Shop works fine the last few months and last sunday the shop wont work...

We have a Strato Managed Server Level 2 and got a Backup working from Saturday. Now two days later thesame problem is there.